# How was this contract created with empty code?

Tags: contract-deployment

I don't understand what happened in this transaction:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0bd55bbf4dfb4e7b15bfed296be3330d5c1116b1bc399a75d3f849edc0d5ac45

The transaction created a contract, sent 1 ETH, supplied `input` data, and did not run out of gas, but the result was a contract with no code.

https://etherscan.io/address/0xd8253352f6044cfe55bcc0748c3fa37b7df81f98#code

What happened here?

Answer (score 2):

I'm new here, so I could definitely be wrong, but I suspect this may be related to an issue that [EIP2](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-2.mediawiki) solves.

The change they describe is:

> If contract creation does not have enough gas to pay for the final gas
>   fee for adding the contract code to the state, the contract creation
>   fails (ie. goes out-of-gas) rather than leaving an empty contract.

And the rationale for their solution is:

> Making contract creation go out-of-gas if there is not enough gas to
>   pay for the final gas fee has the benefits that (i) it creates a more
>   intuitive "success or fail" distinction in the result of a contract
>   creation process, rather than the current "success, fail, or empty
>   contract" trichotomy, (ii) makes failures more easily detectable, as
>   unless contract creation fully succeeds then no contract account will
>   be created at all, and (iii) makes contract creation safer in the case
>   where there is an endowment, as there is a guarantee that either the
>   entire initiation process happens or the transaction fails and the
>   endowment is refunded.

The transaction you mention has a block height less than 1,500,000 which means it happened before the [homestead release](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/introduction/the-homestead-release.html) and before this fix was implemented. I'm new enough that I don't know how to tell how much gas would have been required to put the code into the contract.

If anyone knows more, please comment or edit.

Comment: The transaction did not run out of gas: 300000 limit, 175192 used. Is that still consistent with the pre-EIP2 behavior?

Comment: The 175192 was just to create the contract. Additional gas is needed to add the code. I'm not sure how to tell how much gas would have been needed to add the code in this case. So yes, it is consistent.

Comment: This gives the same answer, old behavior was to create empty contracts in when gas is not enough, but it didn't cause an exception https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions.html#what-could-have-happened-if-an-account-has-storage-value-s-but-no-code-example-http-test-ether-camp-account-5f740b3a43fbb99724ce93a879805f4dc89178b5